How to use Redux-Persist correctly with TypeScript
I am trying to implement Authentication in my project and this is what I made so far. I have made an actions/ folder and in it I created auth.ts and types.ts files, where in auth.ts I have put the actions for the different API calls and the dispatches of the types:
// /actions/auth.ts
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { RootState } from '../reducers';

import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  SET_AUTH_LOADING,
  REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_USER_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_FAIL,
  RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
} from './types';
import { User } from '../actions/types';

// Define action interfaces
interface RegisterSuccessAction {
  type: typeof REGISTER_SUCCESS;
}

interface RegisterFailAction {
  type: typeof REGISTER_FAIL;
}

interface SetAuthLoadingAction {
  type: typeof SET_AUTH_LOADING;
}

interface RemoveAuthLoadingAction {
  type: typeof REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING;
}

interface LoginSuccessAction {
  type: typeof LOGIN_SUCCESS;
}

interface LoginFailAction {
  type: typeof LOGIN_FAIL;
}

interface LoadUserSuccessAction {
  type: typeof LOAD_USER_SUCCESS;
  payload: { user: User };
}

interface LoadUserFailAction {
  type: typeof LOAD_USER_FAIL;
}

interface LogoutSuccessAction {
  type: typeof LOGOUT_SUCCESS;
}

interface LogoutFailAction {
  type: typeof LOGOUT_FAIL;
}

interface ResetRegisterSuccessAction {
  type: typeof RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS;
}

// Union type for all possible actions
export type AuthActionTypes =
  | RegisterSuccessAction
  | RegisterFailAction
  | SetAuthLoadingAction
  | RemoveAuthLoadingAction
  | LoginSuccessAction
  | LoginFailAction
  | LoadUserSuccessAction
  | LoadUserFailAction
  | LogoutSuccessAction
  | LogoutFailAction
  | ResetRegisterSuccessAction;

// Action creators
export const load_user = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthActionTypes>) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/account/user', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    if (res.status === 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: { user: data },
      });

    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: LOAD_USER_FAIL,
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USER_FAIL,
    });
  }
};

export const register = (
  first_name: string,
  last_name: string,
  email: string,
  password: string,
  re_password: string
) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthActionTypes>) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    password,
    re_password,
  });

  dispatch({ type: SET_AUTH_LOADING });

  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/account/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: body,
    });

    if (res.status === 201) {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL });
  }

  dispatch({ type: REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING });
};

export const reset_register_success = () => (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthActionTypes>) => {
  dispatch({ type: RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS });
};

export const login = (email: string, password: string) => async (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<RootState, unknown, AuthActionTypes>
) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  dispatch({ type: SET_AUTH_LOADING });

  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/account/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: body,
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS });
      dispatch(load_user() as any); 
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL });
  }

  dispatch({ type: REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING });
};

export const logout = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch<AuthActionTypes>) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/account/logout', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_FAIL });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_FAIL });
  }
};


// /actions/types.ts
import { Action } from 'redux';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
    company: string;
  }

// Define action types as constants
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_FAIL = "REGISTER_FAIL";
export const SET_AUTH_LOADING = "SET_AUTH_LOADING";
export const REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING = "REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING";
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAIL = "LOGIN_FAIL";
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = "LOGOUT_SUCCESS";
export const LOGOUT_FAIL = "LOGOUT_FAIL";
export const LOAD_USER_SUCCESS = "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS";
export const LOAD_USER_FAIL = "LOAD_USER_FAIL";
export const RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS = "RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS";

// Define action interfaces, ensuring they extend from Redux's `Action`
interface RegisterSuccessAction extends Action<typeof REGISTER_SUCCESS> {}
interface RegisterFailAction extends Action<typeof REGISTER_FAIL> {}
interface SetAuthLoadingAction extends Action<typeof SET_AUTH_LOADING> {}
interface RemoveAuthLoadingAction extends Action<typeof REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING> {}
interface LoginSuccessAction extends Action<typeof LOGIN_SUCCESS> {}
interface LoginFailAction extends Action<typeof LOGIN_FAIL> {}
interface LoadUserSuccessAction extends Action<typeof LOAD_USER_SUCCESS> {
  payload: { user: User };
}
interface LoadUserFailAction extends Action<typeof LOAD_USER_FAIL> {}
interface LogoutSuccessAction extends Action<typeof LOGOUT_SUCCESS> {}
interface LogoutFailAction extends Action<typeof LOGOUT_FAIL> {}
interface ResetRegisterSuccessAction extends Action<typeof RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS> {}

// Union type for all possible actions
export type AuthActionTypes =
  | RegisterSuccessAction
  | RegisterFailAction
  | SetAuthLoadingAction
  | RemoveAuthLoadingAction
  | LoginSuccessAction
  | LoginFailAction
  | LoadUserSuccessAction
  | LoadUserFailAction
  | LogoutSuccessAction
  | LogoutFailAction
  | ResetRegisterSuccessAction;

and I made another folder called reducers where I put the auth.ts and index.ts which export the authReducer and the initial Reducer:
/reducers/auth.ts
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  SET_AUTH_LOADING,
  REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING,
  RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_FAIL,
  LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOAD_USER_FAIL,
} from '../actions/types';
import { AuthActionTypes, User } from '../actions/types';
import { Reducer } from 'redux'; // Import the Reducer type from redux

interface AuthState {
  user: User | null;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  register_success: boolean;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loading: false,
  register_success: false,
};

const authReducer: Reducer<AuthState, AuthActionTypes> = (state = initialState, action): AuthState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        register_success: true,
      };
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      return state;
    case SET_AUTH_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case REMOVE_AUTH_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    case RESET_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        register_success: false,
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
      };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,
      };
    case LOGOUT_FAIL:
      return state;
    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user,
      };
    case LOAD_USER_FAIL:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;

// /actions/index.ts
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

export default rootReducer;

and I made a store.ts:
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer, PersistConfig } from 'redux-persist';
import createWebStorage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage';
import rootReducer, { RootState } from './reducers';
import { AuthActionTypes } from './actions/types';
import { composeWithDevTools } from '@redux-devtools/extension';

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key: string) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key: string, value: string) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key: string) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' ? createWebStorage('local') : createNoopStorage();

const persistConfig: PersistConfig<RootState> = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

// Apply the correct typing to persistReducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer<RootState>(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

Now the problem is that I am getting this error:
Argument of type 'Reducer<{ auth: AuthState; }, AuthActionTypes, Partial<{ auth: never; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<{ auth: AuthState; }, Action>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'AuthActionTypes'.ts(2345)

and I think the types of the AuthActionReducer is not correct. How can I fix this problem?

Have you considered writing modern Redux using Redux-Toolkit? It eliminates the need to write all the boilerplate action strings and types, etc. and works well to infer all the correct types.

thank you so much for this tip!! this would be really helpful, specially that it could reduce the complexity of Redux!!
Thank you
